# How do you check a Rich Text field on an xpage if it has text in it for validation?

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

How do you check a Rich Text field on an xpage if it has text in it for validation?  need this in ssjs.

Thought maybe i could do a getComponent or something, or document1.getItemValue, then check off of that

Answer (score 1):

```
getComponent("inputRichText1").getValue();
```

will work if you want to get any value currently held by the control (after any converters etc.)

```
getComponent("inputRichText1").getSubmittedValue();
```

Will get the value that has been posted to the server before any converters have been applied to it.

Answer (score 0):

Add a validator to the control and simply use the 'value' ssjs variable which would contain the submitted html. Outside a validator use getComponent('body1').getSubmittedValue()